# database schema for a product with multiple categories and hierarchical categories

Tags: database-design

I need some opinion on whether I am going in the right direction with this.

I am trying to build a e-commerce site (with MySQL backend) where

- a single product can belong to more one than category
- categories are hierarchical in nature

For e.g.

```
Food > Fruit > Red > Cherry
     > Fruit > Yellow > Banana
     > Healthy > Cherry
```

- Cherry is both `Healthy` and `Red`.
- There is a hierarchy for categories

The way I am planning to implement this in the backend is:

- [Modified PreOrder traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) for storing hierarchy of categories. The tree would not hold products, but only categories.
- ProductID - CategoryID: many-to-many table: where each product can be stored with multiple categories.

Is this the right way to go ?

One of my concerns in this approach is; even though new categories won't be added very frequently, but when we would have to add a new category, we will have to make a whole lot of updates in productID-cateogryID table since the category IDs would now be pointing to something different!

Is there a better way to deal with this ?

EDIT: Modified preorder traversal is better known as: [Nested Set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are proposing is a good solution for your requirement of M:N products to categories and hierarchical categories.

**To avoid exposing yourself to numerous updates:**
You need to do two things to ensure that you don't have a lot of updates in your intersection table.

First, you need to be sure that your categories have a stable, persistent primary key.

Second, you need to link food items to *leaf categories*.  Don't join `Cherry` to `Red`, `Healthy`, `Fruit` and `Food` - just join it to `Red` and `Healthy`.  Your nested sets take care of all of the secondary (and higher level) associations.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. However, what do you think about the concern I mentioned: `even though new categories won't be added very frequently, but when we would have to add a new category, the left and right values in nested set model will need to be updated and hence referenced categoryIDs will need to be updated in productID-cateogryID table!`

Comment: Absolutely.  The assumption behind visitation numbers (as Joe Celko calls them) is that you read them much more than you write them and so they are worthwhile.  You have two options: 1. Integer left/right numbers mean the whole nested set is recalculated whenever any change is made to the categories - or 2. Float left/right numbers mean that you can restrict updates to the sub-tree that is impacted by using fractional left/right numbers.  I'd recommend using option 1 unless you have so many category updates that it becomes a performance issue.  I'd guess that it won't be a problem.

Comment: Cool. That helps. I am anticipating infrequent category updates, so I think I'll stick with option 1. Thanks.

Comment: Another option is the **Closure table**. See this question for explanation: [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462) Just to clarify: I don't mean that this is better than the Nested Set approach.

Comment: @ypercube - Quite so.  Visitation numbers and closure tables both work more or less equally well.  Depending on what your needs are, I think each approach has small advantages.  Closure tables can definitely be better if you need distance between nodes since this can be recorded directly in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (although I'm not 100% sure myself) I would consider, is to have different tables for different *types* of categories.

For example, 
a table *color* would store red, yellow, etc; 
another table *healthiness* would store healthy, not-healthy, deadly, etc.

The *product* table would then have a *color* column and a *healthiness* column (if 1:N) or you would have 2 more tables, *ProductColor* and *ProductHealthiness* (if N:M).

Comment: Will we run into an issue the moment we have more than two categories I assume?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute why? are you thinking it would require too many joins?

Comment: I was thinking maintenance can be a problem.